# GPS USB device with external coax antenna?

Tags: usb, gps, coax

I've been looking around for a bit searching for a USB connected GPS reciever which i can hook up to my laptop. However, the building i'm sitting at is not ideal for recieving GPS signals but i do however have a antenna tower ontop of the building which i could mount a GPS antenna to, but that would require a long coax connector since the USB cable is not suited for ~300m of wiring through a building.

Anyone know of a good USB-GPS-reciever that has external antenna support? I simply can not find any (pref if it's supported by gpsd in Linux).

This is what i've found so far:
http://www.usglobalsat.com/p-688-bu-353-s4.aspx

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of having a GPS receiver if it never moves?

Comment: @geometrikal: It could serve as a reference station for DGPS (differential GPS), or as a timing reference station. Either way, it would make more sense to use an Ethernet-based receiver and tie it directly to the building's LAN so everyone can make use of the information.

Comment: @DaveTweed is right, if it's for a fixed installation you'd be better off finding an ethernet based device.  These are readily available.

Comment: @geometrikal  GPS is used a lot for precision timing and synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right 300m of USB cable is not suitable, and neither is coax from a practical point of view because even something like LMR-1700 will give you about 17dB of loss over that length. That grade of coax is normally over $10 a meter so you'd have to drop thousands on suitable cable.

You'd be better to place the receiver, antenna and a power source close to outside and transmit the data back in a digital form. RS-485 would be one robust choice for a point-to-point connection but considering how large the building is maybe you already have network infrastructure in place? In that case maybe consider a small Linux SBC that transmits data back over the existing network.

Comment: We had a GPS antenna on the roof of a 20m building.  We had an amplification stage next to the antenna and ran the coax to the receiver in the basement.